# label adjust content when reach max width

Tags: css

What property do I set to my label when I want to continue to next line when It reached my max width.

I tried using

```
overflow:hidden;
```

but what I want is the text will continue in the next line, not clipped.

Here are the properties that I'm using on my label and div.

```
.lblComment {
    width:100%;
    font-size:10px;
    min-height:20px;
}

.divComment {
    width:880;
    max-width:880;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:thin;
    border-color:red;
}
```

Comment: It could be hyphens: auto; or white-space:normal; depending on your markup.

Comment: They are not working. :(

Comment: what tag are you using as label? <span>?

Comment: I'm use label inside a div.

Comment: You setting max width using max-width css property? Maybe your text does not have any spaces, tabs or end of lines?

Comment: Yes It has max-width. the div is not expanding, only the text. Yes I don't have those because the text comes from the database and it's a comment field.

Comment: I've added my CCS on the question.

Comment: Maybe word-break:break-all; will help.

Comment: Also it is pretty strange that comment text does not have any spaces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the text doesn't have any spaces, you need to force wrapping to break the word on `.lblComment`:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g3X33/1/)

Comment: No problems :). Glad I could help.